# Are humans capable of thinking of a series of random numbers?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind

I read in a book today ( the computer music tutorial by curtis roads), that humans are not capable of imagining any long series of truly random numbers. Apparently, the only way to generate a series of truly random numbers is to use either a Geiger counter or some type of cellular automata algorithm. Is it true that a computer would be able to detect a pattern and accurately guess the nth number in a series of random numbers thought up by a person?

Comment: Can you define random? Any finite sequence of numbers can be generated by a polynomial.

Comment: @user4894  I wish I'd have thought of that!  Very concise.  I just spent 20 minutes typing in a reply when the question was closed to answers!  Live and learn.

Comment: no computer could predict it with absolute accuracy.